# dll.config not found asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, api

I'm developing asp.net application that uses a 3rd party API, and one of the API use a config file (dll.config).

I access the function in the API using class (.cs) file.  When I try to run it, it throws a file not exception and the API won't start.

I tried to run exact same code in the WPF approach, the code works fine.

After review and searching, I tried to use configuration manager yet it does not solve my problem.

Here I attach what I've tried.

```
public void config3()
{
    string path = "E:\\LiveStreaming\\testLiveStreaming\\testLiveStreaming\\bin\\Bosch.Dcn.Ecpc.Client.Logic.dll.config";
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("path " + path);

    try
    {
        RemotingConfiguration.Configure(path, false);
    }
    catch (Exception et)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("error conf " + et.Message);
    }
}
```

The thrown error from debug console.

> DebugCategory Information: 3 : An error occurred in DCN-SW API
>   initializing the server link: .Config file
>   'Bosch.Dcn.Ecpc.Client.Logic.dll.config' cannot be read successfully
>   due to exception 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot
>   find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)    at
>   System.BaseConfigHandler.RunParser(String fileName)    at
>   System.ConfigTreeParser.Parse(String fileName, String configPath,
>   Boolean skipSecurityStuff)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Activation.RemotingXmlConfigFileParser.ParseConfigFile(String
>   filename)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingConfigHandler.LoadConfigurationFromXmlFile(String
>   filename)'. DebugCategory Information: 4 : Availability state of the
>   DCN-SW API changed from b to a.

here is my web.config file

```
  <configuration>

  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings">
      <section name="Bosch.Dcn.Ecpc.Client.Logic.dll" type="Bosch.Dcn.Ecpc.Client.Logic,Bosch.Dcn.Ecpc.Client.Logic, Version=4.43.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=99e028c462dbcff9" allowLocation="true" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <applicationSettings >

    <Bosch.Dcn.Ecpc.Client.Logic.dll>
      <configuration>
        <system.runtime.remoting>
          <application>
            <channels>
              <channel ref="tcp" port="0" username="">
                <clientProviders>
                  <formatter ref="binary"/>
                </clientProviders>
                <serverProviders>
                  <formatter ref="binary" typeFilterLevel="Full"/>
                </serverProviders>
              </channel>
            </channels>
          </application>
        </system.runtime.remoting>
        <startup>
          <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
        </startup>
      </configuration>
    </Bosch.Dcn.Ecpc.Client.Logic.dll>
  </applicationSettings>


  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer></configuration>
```

Comment: Please copy your source code and error message as text.

Comment: How are you including the config file in your project?  I am guessing, but I'd say that the dll is being copied to the bin folder of the project, but the config file is not.  You may need to include it in your project, and set the `Build Action` to `Content` and set `Copy to Output Directory` to `true`.

Comment: i have copied the config file to bin folder but still the compiler thrown such error.

Comment: @BrendanGreen can you please suggest any method that i can try to resolve this ? tq

Comment: Make sure that you follow Brendan Greens detail about making sure the Bosch.Dcn.Ecpc.Client.Logic.dll  dll is included in the web project as a reference and it has its reference property set to copy to output bin.     After a compile do you see the bosch dll in your bin directory along with a web.config that has this custom section info in it?   also make sure that if Bosh dll has dependencies they are copied also.

Comment: @SqlSurfer i've checked the bin folder and it does have both dll and it config file.

Comment: Your bosh dll may be using its dll assembly name as a custom config file name.   So you need to have a config file named  'Bosch.Dcn.Ecpc.Client.Logic.dll.config'   in your directory with the above cofnig info in it.   Also remove the trailing space at the end of applicationSettings in the opening element

Comment: @SqlSurfer what do you mean by "having the file in your directory" . the file is present in the project directory.. it's killing me ..